# Add variable in Retrofit Model, apart from response

Tags: java, android, retrofit

I am using Retrofit for consuming REST APIs and its working fine. However I am using same model of retrofit, for the purpose of RecyclerView and I have added and extra variable/field "isChecked" for another purpose for Adapter, in Retrofit Model. I have set by default isChecked to false. But when I call API, Retrofit automatically set isChecked to null. (In the response there is no object with isChecked key).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the keyword. **transient**

Sample

```
//..

transient boolean isChecked = true;

//..

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

As a different method, you can mark the relevant fields in the data model for retrofit with **@Expose**.

```
//..
public class SampleClass {

    @SerializedName("sample")
    @Expose
    public String sample;
    public boolean isChecked;

}
//..
```